# Exporting grid of plots as .svg in bokeh

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, export, bokeh

I am using the Bokeh library code [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/anscombe.html), and trying to export the whole plot (not the text) as a .svg file.

The problem is if I try the following approach:

```py
from bokeh.io import export_png
plot.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(plot, filename="plot.svg")
```

I get `NameError: name 'plot' is not defined`

If I replace 'plot' with 'grid', it gives me an attribute error.

How can I export the whole gridplot as a .svg?

Comment: There is already an issue to [deal with this](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9169). I hope it will be solved in the 2.0 version. In the mean time you can export all the SVG gathered in a pdf report as I did in [this example](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/generate-svg-images-from-bokeh-plots-and-include-them-in-a-pdf-report-with-using-svglib-and-reportlab/3889)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I export the whole gridplot as a .svg?

You can't. SVG export works by replacing the standard HTML raster canvas with a "CanvasSVG" that can output SVG when standard HTML canvas drawing calls are made to it. But Bokeh grid plots are not on one giant HTML canvas. They are a grid of separate HTML canvases, which means there is only the possibility of getting a separate SVG for each (if you turn `output_backend = "svg"` for each subplot individually)

UPDATE: In case it is useful, someone one the Discourse reported on using pdflib to stitch the SVGs together in post processing:

https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/generate-svg-images-from-bokeh-plots-and-include-them-in-a-pdf-report-with-using-svglib-and-reportlab/3889

Comment: Thank you. What would be my best bet for exporting the file and maximizing its resolution? Is exporting as png the best other option?

Comment: You can export PNG at any resolution you want, by passing the dimensions to `export_png`. Alternatively, I have *heard* it is possible to stitch multiple SVGs together somehow. So that might be an option, but I have no personal experience with it so I cannot do more than mention the possibility